# Applying jQuery code to AJAX loaded content

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have these **HTML** lines

```
<h1 class="trigger">HEADLINE ONE</h1>
<div class="toggle_container">
    BODY TEXT ONE
</div>
```

and this **jQuery** code in the `<head>` section of my site

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.trigger').not('.trigger_active').next('.toggle_container').hide();
    $('.trigger').click( function() {
        var trig = $(this);
        if ( trig.hasClass('trigger_active') ) {
            trig.next('.toggle_container').slideToggle('slow');
            trig.removeClass('trigger_active');
        } else {
            $('.trigger_active').next('.toggle_container').slideToggle('slow');
            $('.trigger_active').removeClass('trigger_active');
            trig.next('.toggle_container').slideToggle('slow');
            trig.addClass('trigger_active');
        };
        return false;
    });
});
```

After the page is loaded and the jQuery code is applied, my **HTML** output looks like this:

```
<h1 class="trigger">HEADLINE ONE</h1>
<div class="toggle_container" style="display: none;">
     BODY TEXT ONE
</div>
```

So far everything works fine. But here comes my problem: When I'm loading a new **HTML** block with AJAX - which looks like this:

```
<h1 class="trigger">HEADLINE TWO</h1>
<div class="toggle_container">
    BODY TEXT TWO
</div>
```

... it doesn't get rendered with the above jQuery code. So how can I apply the jQuery code to this new loaded HTML block?

**EDIT: HERE's THE AJAX**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // The number of the next page to load (/page/x/).
    var pageNum = parseInt(pbd_alp.startPage) + 1;

    // The maximum number of pages the current query can return.
    var max = parseInt(pbd_alp.maxPages);

    // The link of the next page of posts.
    var nextLink = pbd_alp.nextLink;

    /**
     * Replace the traditional navigation with our own,
     * but only if there is at least one page of new posts to load.
     */
    if(pageNum <= max) {
        // Insert the "More Posts" link.
        $('#content')
            .append('<div class="pbd-alp-placeholder-'+ pageNum +'"></div>')
            .append('<p id="pbd-alp-load-posts"><a href="#">↓ Archive</a></p>');

        // Remove the traditional navigation.
        $('.navigation').remove();
    }


    /**
     * Load new posts when the link is clicked.
     */
    $('#pbd-alp-load-posts a').click(function() {



        // Are there more posts to load?
        if(pageNum <= max) {

            // Show that we're working.
            $(this).text('...');

            $('.pbd-alp-placeholder-'+ pageNum).load(nextLink + ' .post',
                function() {
                    // Update page number and nextLink.
                    pageNum++;
                    nextLink = nextLink.replace(/\/page\/[0-9]?/, '/page/'+ pageNum);

                    // Add a new placeholder, for when user clicks again.
                    $('#pbd-alp-load-posts')
                        .before('<div class="pbd-alp-placeholder-'+ pageNum +'"></div>')

                    // Update the button message.
                    if(pageNum <= max) {
                        $('#pbd-alp-load-posts a').text('Older entries');
                    } else {
                        $('#pbd-alp-load-posts a').text('All items loaded.');
                    }
                }
            );
        } else {
            $('#pbd-alp-load-posts a').append('.');
        }   

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: The code used to perform said ajax is important to solving this problem.

Comment: As @KevinB states you should post your ajax code, because as user3558931 points out in his answer, is there where you'll have to run the part of code which hides the "toggle_cotainer" after load the HTML

Comment: Added the AJAX code ...

Answer (score 4):

After the ajax content is successfully appended to the DOM you want to run the following piece of code again:

```
$('.trigger').not('.trigger_active').next('.toggle_container').hide();
```

Then you want to make sure that you use event delegation so the clicking will also work on the dynamically inserted content:

```
$(document).on('click', '.trigger', function() {
    //the rest of your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you load the partial html with AJAX, your javascript in head won't get executed.

Potential solution

Have the following script in head

```
function init(){
$('.trigger').not('.trigger_active').next('.toggle_container').hide();
    $('.trigger').click( function() {
        var trig = $(this);
        if ( trig.hasClass('trigger_active') ) {
            trig.next('.toggle_container').slideToggle('slow');
            trig.removeClass('trigger_active');
        } else {
            $('.trigger_active').next('.toggle_container').slideToggle('slow');
            $('.trigger_active').removeClass('trigger_active');
            trig.next('.toggle_container').slideToggle('slow');
            trig.addClass('trigger_active');
        };
        return false;
    });
}

$(document).ready( function() {
    init();
});
```

And in the HTML loaded by the AJAX should look like this

```
<h1 class="trigger">HEADLINE TWO</h1>
<div class="toggle_container">
    BODY TEXT TWO
</div>
<script>init();</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't add 'display:none' to the HTML loaded by AJAX :(